# Way to set default Rails Cache-Control header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-5, rack

I know that to set the Cache-Control header in my own controllers I can call `#expires_now`, but my Rails app uses an engine ([apitome](https://github.com/jejacks0n/apitome)), and on those requests, the Cache-Control header gets set to `max-age=0, private, must-revalidate`. I see that may be the default value for Rack::ETag [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb#L16), but I can't figure out how to override it.

When I set `Rails.configuration.public_file_server.headers = { 'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache' }`, that changes the header for my javascript assets for example, but not the engine.

Is there a way to override the default or a good way to set this setting in the engine? Maybe just monkey patch the controller and add a before_action to set the header?